# The change of quadratic form: $l_p$-norm to $l_2$-norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, positive-definite

I am confused about the following quadratic form on page 476 of [Boyd & Vandenberghe](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/),

$$\|z\|_P = (z^TPz)^{1/2} = \|P^{1/2}z\|_2$$

where $P \in \textbf{S}_{++}^n$. My understanding is that this expression gives a way of changing over from $l_p$-norm to $l_2$-norm by using a positive definite matrix $P$. I wonder if there is any formulation for $P$ in general? The author only provides one example for $l_1$-norm in Subsection 9.4.2 on page 477. I want to know how the matrix $P$ would be like. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here. The notation $\|z\|_P$ is absolutely not the same as $\|z\|_p$! In fact $l_p$ norms for $p\neq 2$ cannot have such an expression, because they can't be derived from an inner product. Indeed, any norm induced by an inner product must satisfy the parallelogram identity
$$2\lVert u\rVert^2 + 2\lVert v\rVert^2 = \lVert u + v\rVert^2 + \lVert u - v\rVert^2;$$
but $l_p$ norms do not satisfy this, as for example
$$4=2\lVert (1,0)\rVert_p^2 + 2\lVert (0,1)\rVert_p^2 \neq \lVert (1,1)  \rVert_p^2 + \lVert (1,-1)\rVert_p^2=2^{1+\frac2p}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As Arnaud mentioned, you have misunderstood the formula: it defines the norm induced by the $P$ matrix and how it relates to the $l_2$ norm.

Notice that

$
\|z\|_I = \|z\|_2 = l_2(z).
$